# PIG mapreduce output and HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, mapreduce, apache-pig

I have a file called test.txt with the records as below (disregard the dots):

```
"1" "a" "x" 
"2" "b" "y" 
"3" "c" "z"
```

(tab as field separator)

My pig script (test.pig):

```
a=LOAD '/Analytics/warehouse/SF/test.txt' as (fullrecord:chararray);

b=FOREACH a generate REPLACE($0,'\t',',');

STORE b INTO 'hdfs://localhost:9000/Analytics/warehouse/SF/sf.out' USING PigStorage(',');
```

I run the script with: `pig -x mapreduce test.pig`

the output:

```
.../warehouse/SF/sf.out

part-m-0000
```

And the content is only:

```
"1"
"2"
"3"
```

Q1- What happened with the other fields?

Q2- Why the tab characters wasn't changed by ","?

Q3- How can i achieve the next result?

```
"1","a","x" 
"2","b","y" 
"3","c","z"
```

Q4- How can i query that result with HIVE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What happened with the other fields

LOAD defaults to using tab delimiter. Your `GENERATE` only grabbed the first column. You need `USING PigStorage('\n')` to load the whole line. But you can also not do this, and just remove the `FOREACH`, then STORE with `PigStorage(',')`

> Why the tab characters wasn't changed

Related to above, there is nothing to replace when you only have one element.

> How can i query that result with HIVE?

Use HCatalog, not PigStorage -

```
STORE data_alias INTO 'tablename' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatStorer();
```

Then query the table.

Or you would need to define a Hive External table over the HDFS data.

You can also skip using Pig altogether; Hive can query files that have tabs - `STORED AS TEXT FIELDS DELIMITED BY '\t'`